# Fluent Assertion namespace not recognised

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-assertions

I am using .Net version 4.6.1 and have installed fluent assertion 3.3.0 on an MVC4 project, but the namespace is not being recognised in the Unit Test of the project.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project? Sometimes NuGet packages are resolved after/during building. Maybe do a Clean & Rebuild and see if this helps? Just tested your setup in a local solution and saw these versions should work just fine.

Comment: Do you installed fluent assertion into UnitTestProject?

Comment: Yes I did, also .NET 4.6.1

Comment: On a related note, why are you still using that ancient version? 4.x has been around for almost two years now, and the first betas of 5.0 have been shipped recently

Comment: Hi @DennisDoomen, it's the first one I started with and am still learning with, so wanted to master everything I can first and then move up to the latest :D

Answer (score 2):

Have just found the answer!  It was installed in the project already, but I needed to go back into Nuget package manager in order to then install it onto the Unit Test project.  Thank you for the suggestions!